# Animate changing textures with keyframes in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation, texturing, node-editor

In Blender internal render the Textures tab has checkboxes that can be keyframed. This means you can change textures by unchecking and checking. An example would be if you had 3 different textures with eyes (1 is open, 2 is half open, 3 is closed) and you key them to simulate the texture animation.

Is there a similar way to do that in Cycles Render, because those boxes don't appear.

Comment: Switch textures by MixRGB node, Fac slider from 0 to 1

Comment: See: [Cycles, animate the color on part of an object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66646/cycles-animate-the-color-on-part-of-an-object/66648#66648)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you animate image texture materials in blender cycles with keyframes?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36748/how-do-you-animate-image-texture-materials-in-blender-cycles-with-keyframes)

Comment: Possibly related: [Animating eye texture in a head mesh](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18363/animating-eye-texture-in-a-head-mesh)