# How to make an animation where the colour of the object changes

Tags: animation

I want to make my emision material ball switch colors.
I thought it was as simple as Setting keyframes and changing the color, but it won't work.

Comment: Please show your Blender work as a screen capture.

Comment: Did you render an image sequence or is this a 3D View Window observation?  The View Color can be different than the render color.  Please render at points where you would expect to see a colour change.

Comment: Hello :). This thread could help https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/66646/78972

Comment: Mix RGB and keyframes the factor from 0 to 1 or whatever